# How can I change the numbers in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I add this `[B]` and `[/B]` with the numbers with jQuery?

I want to change this numbers:

```
<body>
<textarea id='A' cols="40" rows="10">
505|490 507|487 502|485 500|485 505|485 501|484 510|486 501|483 507|484
</textarea>
</body>
```

to

```
<body>
<textarea id='A' cols="40" rows="10">
[B]505|490[/B]
[B]507|487[/B]
[B]502|485[/B]
[B]500|485[/B]
[B]505|485[/B]
[B]501|484[/B]
[B]510|486[/B]
[B]501|483[/B]
[B]507|484[/B]
[B]507|487[/B]
[B]502|485[/B]
[B]500|485[/B]
[B]505|485[/B]
[B]501|484[/B]
[B]510|486[/B]
[B]501|483[/B]
[B]507|484[/B]
</textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: Before posting on this website do at least one search on google...`$.text()`, `$.val()` `$.html()`. Check this out

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
$('#A').val(function(_,h){ return h.replace(/(\S+)\s*/g,'[B]$1[/B]\n') })
```

It will also work if you have more elements in your jQuery object (for example with `$('textarea')`).

Comment: That's nice even i guess should be trimed as here: http://jsfiddle.net/avYMJ/1/

Comment: Just one thing, could you explain this behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/avYMJ/2/ ???

Comment: [Better](http://jsfiddle.net/tbXb6/) ? The space wasn't replaced.

Comment: @dystroy simple like that! Thx for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var parts = $("#A").val().split(" ");
$("#A").val(function() {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        str += "[B]" + parts[i] + "[/B]";
    }
    return str;
});
```

Comment: Just updating your code: http://jsfiddle.net/avYMJ/

Answer (score -1):

```
var parts = $("#A").val().split(" ");
$("#A").val(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        parts[i] = "[B]" + parts[i] + "[/B]";
    }
    return parts.join('\n');
});
```